# ASA DHCP relay configuration

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I have locations in different cities, connected using 2 Cisco ASA devices.

My main location, corporate, use the IP 192.168.1.x The second location, remote store, use the IP 192.168.3.x

I have a DHCP server (192.168.1.254) at my corporate location. I have created a scope for the 192.168.1.x which works fine for the corporate location.

I created a scope for the remote location (192.168.3.x) on my DHCP server and tried to configure the remote ASA DCHP Relay,

on the remote ASA: I disabled the DHCP Server on the inside. I enabled DHCP Relay on the inside, with set route set at yes.

I set the Global DHCP Relay Servers, specify up to four servers to which DHCP requests would be relayed. I added my DHCP, 192.168.1.254

I flashed these settings to the ASA and gave it a try, didn't do anything.

Am I missing something - forgetting something. not really sure what im doing wrong.

DHCP Settings on remote ASA:

```
dhcp-client update dns server both
dhcpd dns 192.168.1.254
dhcpd ping_timeout 750
dhcpd domain JEWELS.LOCAL
dhcpd auto_config outside
dhcpd update dns both
!
dhcpd address 192.168.3.2-192.168.3.33 inside
!
dhcprelay server 192.168.1.254 outside
dhcprelay enable inside
dhcprelay setroute inside
```

On my local ASA:
I have two ACLs for UDP ports 67  and 68 permitting any inbound traffic from the remote locations IP ...

```
dhcprelay timeout 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you can ping your DHCP server address from your remote ASA.
If you can, check to make sure you have the following commands configured on the remote ASA:

dhcprelay server *192.168.1.254 or your dhcp address* outside

dhcprelay enable inside

dhcprelay setroute inside

dhcprelay timeout *Enough time to reach server*

Comment: yes - whenever i ping i get an immediate respone. i even tried tracert to the dhcp server, 1 hop. communication is perfect between the locations. however whenever i try an ipconfig /renew it says it cannot communicate with the DHCP server. i'm going to edit my original question with the DHCP config i pulled from a telnet session with the ASA.

Comment: also - the two locations are connected using site-to-site vpn ..

Comment: I had to add some additions to this (acls and nat translations for the remote store) don't remember exactly, cisco support actually helped with the setp